# Run android project even if .xml file is visible in editor

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno . In that whenever I tried to run my android project while .xml file is visible it is not able to run but if .java file is visible then i am able to run my project.

Why this is happen. Is this the new functionality of IDE? If I want to run my application even if xml is visible on editor how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you start running your Application from Java file which inturn calls your xml file, you are required to start running your application from java file. It is the same in any version of Eclipse.

Comment: you can see in helios of any old version before juno. if you do some changes in .xml file and from there only you run the app. you can able to run it. this is not the case for juno. @Narasimhan . dont know why?